# How to show disappearing from a point?

Tags: ios, ios4

I am designing an app that requires a view with a X (cross) button on upper left corner every thing works fine i want to remove view when X button clicked the whole view will disappears from that X button as snaps in the camera roll when they deleted 
I am new in iphone development any one please tell via link to tutorial or code 
Thanks in advance

Comment: do you mean you want the view to shrink into the X as it is disappearing?

Comment: Yes shrink to X and the disappear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CGPoint myExitIconCenter = myExitIcon.center;
CGRect endRect = CGRectMake(myExitIconCenter.x, myExitIconCenter.y, 0, 0);

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animation:^{
     meViewBeingClosed.frame = endRect;
} completion: ^(BOOL finished) {
     [meViewBeingClosed removeFromSuperview];
}];
```